# parametric equation describing part of an arc

Tags: geometry

I am trying to draw a profile which has as a section the arc **AB** in the following picture:

[image]

The arc **AB** is a section of the green circle with origin **C** and radius $C_d$:
$$\left(y-y_c\right)^2 + \left(x-x_c\right)^2 = C_d^2$$

Points **A** and **B** are known as a function of the angle between sections, i.e.
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos\alpha_t,\sin\alpha_t\right] \quad B = \frac{D_r}{2}\left[\cos\left(\alpha_t+\alpha_f\right),\sin\left(\alpha_t+\alpha_f\right)\right]$$

where $\alpha_t$ is the angle **OA** makes with the horizontal and $\alpha_f$ is the angle $\sphericalangle AOB$. Note that in this case $\alpha_t+\alpha_f$ happens to sum to $\pi/2$ but that is not always the case.

Knowing these points and with the condition that the green circle with radius $C_d$ passes through both points it is possible to determine **C**. It is then possible to construct the arc **AB** after having determined the angle $\sphericalangle ACB$.

What i would like to know is if, given the above information, it is also possible to construct the section **AB** with **O** as the origin? I would like a parametric equation of arc **AB** as function of the angle ($\alpha_t\le\alpha\le\alpha_t+\alpha_f$) without changing origin from **O** to **C**.

Comment: Some nitpicking: given points $A$ and $B$ and radius $C_d$, there are two possible candidates for $C$.  

As for your actual question, the equation of a circle in polar coordinate is maybe what you want? To be honest I don't really understand the question. Judging from the title you want a parametric equation of arc $\mathbf{AB}$ without changing your origin.  

If that's not what you want, a better explanation or more context would be very welcomed.

Comment: @N.Bach - Agreed, point C is one of two possibilities however it is the only correct one as that provides the arc in the correct orientation. As you say I would indeed like to know if it is possible to get a parametric equation of arc AB as function of the angle ($\alpha_t\lt\alpha\le\alpha_t+\alpha_f$) without changing origin from **O** to **C**.

Comment: "In this case it is no longer a circle": why would the nature of the angle change ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust - It won't be a circle with repect to **O**, right? it would be an ellipse of some sort

Comment: @nluigi: no, it's a circle of center $C$ and remains a circle of center $C$ forever, unless you want to *approximate* it with another curve.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I dont think i am making myself clear; any point on the arc **AB** has the same distance to point **C** so clearly those points are part of a circle with center **C**. However, those same points on arc **AB** are not the same distance from point **O**, therefore those points with respect to point **O** are not described by a circle but by... (I am guessing an ellipse with center **O**)?

Comment: @nluigi Your terminology is a little confusing, but your last comment is pretty clear about what you mean. And no, it wouldn't be an ellipse with focal $O$. Regardless of origin, the shape of arc $AB$ will remain that of a circular arc, and afaik there are no other name for it. Describing a circle from a point that is not the center is not very nice, but that would not make it an ellipse. (well circle are trivial ellipses, but you get the point [I hope])

Comment: @nluigi: you'd better say "the distance of the points of the arc to $O$ is not constant" so that the polar equation with pole at $O$ cannot be of the form $\rho=r$. This doesn't change the circular nature of the arc and indeed doesn't make it an ellipse nor anything else. I guess that you should provide more context to help us give more useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $C$ has polar coordinates $(d,\varphi)$, then the circle centered at $C$ with radius $C_d$ is the collection of points M $(\rho,\theta)$ that satsify:
$$
\operatorname{distance}(C,M)^2
=\rho^2-2\rho d\cos\left( \theta-\varphi \right)+d^2=C_d^2
$$
In particular the circular arc between $A\left(\frac 12,\ \alpha_t\right)$ and $B\left(\frac{D_r}2,\ \alpha_t+\alpha_f\right)$
corresponds to points $M$ whose $\theta$ coordinate is in between $\alpha_t$ and $\alpha_t+\alpha_f$ (assuming that $\alpha_f$ satisfies some reasonable assumptions, as usual when dealing with angles)

### EDIT

Important note I forgot to mention, for one $\theta$ value, you may end up with several possible $\rho$ values, so you need to differentiate them...

After re-reading your question, I guess you would have preferred something of the form "$\rho(\theta)=$ something".
I don't really recommend it, but it's possible to achieve that
\begin{align*}
\rho^2-2\rho d\cos\left( \theta-\varphi \right)+d^2=C_d^2
&\iff \big( \rho-d\cos\left(\theta-\varphi\right) \big)^2-d^2\cos^2(\theta-\varphi)+d^2=C_d^2\\
&\iff \big( \rho-d\cos\left(\theta-\varphi\right) \big)^2=C_d^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)\\
&\iff \rho= d\cos(\theta-\varphi) \pm \sqrt{C^2_d-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)}
\end{align*}
Note that this formula, is not always properly defined! When the origin is not inside the circle, there are values of $\theta$ for which
$$
C_d^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi) < 0
$$
Also when the square root is actually defined, you in general obtain 2 possible values for $\rho(\theta)$. If the origin is not in the circle, you need both values. If the origin is inside, you can keep only the positive value, the negative one should be properly retrieved for the opposite $\theta$.

### EDIT 2

The easy case for you is when the origin is inside the circle, you get a nice parametric equation and you can safely take the portion for which $\alpha_t\le\theta\le\alpha_t+\alpha_f$.
When the origin is not inside the circle, there are two limit angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ such that
$C_d^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta_i-\varphi)=0$. These limit angles split the space of $\theta$ values into two connected parts:

- $C^2_d-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)<0$ and there are no well-defined $\rho$ values
- $C_d^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)>0$, and we obtain two circular curves
  $\rho_1(\theta)=d\cos(\theta-\varphi)+\sqrt{C^2_d-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)}$
  and
  $\rho_2(\theta)=d\cos(\theta-\varphi)-\sqrt{C^2_d-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi)}$.
  These two curves join together at the limit angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
  If you're lucky $A$ and $B$ both belong to the same curve. If you're not, you must take a portion of each curve.

### EDIT 3

Concerning how to derive the distance equation, I think it is standard when using polar coordinates. I don't remember the "normal" proof but this is how I personally remember it:
\begin{align*}
\left\| C-M \right\|^2
&= \left\| C-O \right\|^2 -2\langle C-O,\ M-O\rangle +\left\| M-O \right\|^2\\
&= \rho^2 -2\rho d\cos\left( \overrightarrow{OC},\ \overrightarrow{OM} \right)+d^2\\
&=\rho^2-2\rho d\cos(\theta-\varphi)+d^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Your edit contains the answer to my question, i was looking for an explicit function $\rho\left(\theta\right)$, sorry if that still wasn't clear. Why don't you recommend this form? because the condition $C_d^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\varphi) < 0$ may occur?

Comment: Also how is the distance equation derived? Is it an application of the law of cosines?

Comment: @nluigi I guess it's time for an edit 3...
I don't recommend the other form since you may have that condition of $C^2_d-d^2\sin^2 <0$, and because I don't like square roots. But when you need an explicit form, it is still useful, and you see the constraints on your parameters better. The first form just feels nicer to me, but has implicit constraints.

Comment: @nluigi Just checked what the law of cosine is, and it is in fact the law of cosine. I don't call it that usually so I wasn't sure (I didn't learn maths in English).

Comment: I guess i am not so lucky, $A$ and $B$ are never on the same curve :)

Comment: @nluigi if you're extra unlucky, both $A$ and $B$ belong to the same curve, but you need to take two small pieces of that curve plus all of the other curve! Yeah, kinda forgot this case because I was too lazy to make a drawing.

Comment: Guess I am not so unlucky after all, I was able to implement the explicit formula for $\rho(\theta)$ directly only having to account for changing $\gamma$. Furthermore, it so happens to be the case that the determinant is always positive so there was no need to deal with different cases! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If I am right, you want the polar equation of a circle when the center is vertically shifted from the pole. Let us assume unit radius and relative shift $s$.

The parametric equation of the shifted circle can be written

$$\begin{cases}x=\cos t,\\y=\sin t+s.\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\rho^2=\cos^2t+(\sin t+s)^2=1+s^2+2s\sin t,$$

gives

$$\sin t=\frac{\rho^2-1-s^2}{2s}.$$

And

$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin t+s}{\cos t}=\frac{\rho^2-1+s^2}{\sqrt{4s^2-\left(\rho^2-1-s^2\right)^2}}.$$

Squaring and rearranging, you will obtain a biquadratic equation in $\rho$ which will give you $\rho$ as a function of $\theta$.